# Is there a way to set minimum width on individual columns in C1FlexGrid?

Tags: vb.net, column-width, c1flexgrid

Working with vb.net WinForms. I can set minimum width for the column collection of the flexgrid, but is there a way to make the minimum width different for each column? I cannot find anything that supports this. Pretty straightforward question but if any more info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer C1FlexGrid versions provide the feature "Column.StarWidth", which is used to size all columns based on the available space in the parent control.
Here, you can specify a min width for each col:

```
c1FlexGrid.Cols(2).StarWidth = "*";
c1FlexGrid.Cols(2).MinWidth = 100;
```

See https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/win/online-flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4.5.2~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Column~MinWidth.html

Comment: Forgot to come back and update your answer. Thank you very much this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The grid has a Cols property, you pass in the index of the column, then the Column has a width property:

Example:

```
grid.Cols[0].Width = 50
```

References
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid.html
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.ColumnCollection.html
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Column_members.html
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Column~Width.html